# Wrong order of y values in ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got 3 groups, each one showing the number of sales for two types of clients (historical and tele-rehab).
I'm trying to plot the sales in the order I defined them:

**In the BI gain group:**

First sale is historical, black colour = 30

Second sale is tele-rehab. white colour = 20

**In the BI efficiency:**

First sale is historical, black colur = 49

Second sale is tele-rehab, white colur = 47

**In the BI effectiveness:**

First sale is historical, black colour =58

Second sale is tele-rehab, white colur=60

When I try to plot it ggplot changes the order of the sales

```
ibrary(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(stadium=c('BI gain', 'BI efficiency', 'BI effectiveness'),
                 food=c('historical','tele-rehab', 'historical','tele-rehab', 'historical','tele-rehab'),
                 sales=c(30.0, 20.0, 49.0, 47.0, 58.0, 60.0))
df$stadium <- as.factor(df$stadium)
df$stadium <- factor(df$stadium, levels=unique(df$stadium))

df$sales<-as.numeric(as.character(df$sales))


ggplot(df, aes(fill=food, y=sales, x=stadium)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity',colour="black")+
  scale_fill_manual ('Where', values = c("black","white"))
```

I defined the sales as numeric, but ggplot changes the order.

Comment: Is your data correct in the way you defined it?

Comment: Something must be wrong but I can't see what.. the first bar in the plot should be y= 30, the second should be y= 20.... as I definded in the dataframe

Comment: ggplot does not change the order. You are assigning the wrong `stadiums` to `sales`. According to your description you have to do `stadium = rep(c("BI gain", "BI efficiency", "BI effectiveness"), each = 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you defined your dateframe. You listed the stadiums only once each and thus R does autofill then. Just list all the possible stadiums in your dataframe. See code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(stadium=c('BI gain', 'BI gain', 
                           'BI efficiency', 'BI efficiency', 
                           'BI effectiveness', 'BI effectiveness'),
                 food=c('historical','tele-rehab', 
                        'historical','tele-rehab', 
                        'historical','tele-rehab'),
                 sales=c(30.0, 20.0, 
                         49.0, 47.0, 
                         58.0, 60.0))
df$stadium <- as.factor(df$stadium)
df$stadium <- factor(df$stadium, levels=unique(df$stadium))

df$sales<-as.numeric(as.character(df$sales))


ggplot(df, aes(fill=food, y=sales, x=stadium)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity',colour="black")+
  scale_fill_manual ('Where', values = c("black","white"))
```

Comment: I like to acknowledge the great comment of @stefan above which was posted while I wrote my answer and add that the most efficient way to define the data frame would be (maybe relevant for larger data frames): `df <- data.frame(stadium = rep(c("BI gain", "BI efficiency", "BI effectiveness"), each = 2), food=rep(c('historical', 'tele-rehab'), 3), sales=c(30.0, 20.0, 49.0, 47.0, 58.0, 60.0))`